# Adding parameters on server side to limit users access to data

Tags: c#, odata

I am using .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework to access an Oracle database.
I need to limit how much data I return from an OData query based on the role-based security we have implemented in our database tables.

I am thinking to override the Get function and add the extra query filters that limit the data to only the data they are authorised to see.

But I am new to OData and not sure how to do this. If it can be done.

Comment: Well, I think according to this : http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/rdb/pdf/tech_archive/rdb70_role_based_security.pdf , if you are already not connecting with the correct user/user group, you will be denied to access certain objects that you are not assigned to. So, I believe you could just change the connection string based on the role?

Comment: Are you using WCF Data Services or Web API to generate your Odata endpoint?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web API v4, try this [sample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataAuthorizationQueryValidatorSample), customize your own attribute to limit user access to data.